# Build a Raster GIS Web Application

Tags: raster, open-source-gis, software-recommendations

We need to build a Web based GIS application for Raster data computation (analysis). All the maps are in form of raster images.

We are failing from a week to find a proper tool which allows fetching, viewing and computing of raster data easily. Let me mention here, We need to work on open source tools.

Can you please guide me to proper direction?

---

I have checked WCS on web. But frankly I am very unsure how to proceed further. A step wise guide would seriously help me a lot.

Comment: What sort of raster analysis do you plan to perform? I guess that basic histogram/mean/max/min will not be enough, or? You say web application, does it mean that users should be able to do analysis with browser without installing any thick client like QGIS, OSSIM, SAGA GIS, Opticks GIS etc?

Comment: I would agree with user30184, it depends on what kind of "computing" you want to do. There are many web applications that let you fetch and view raster images. If you want to analyze them with a spatial context you could be better off using a desktop client like the ones being listed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should investigate the [Web Coverage Service (WCS)](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wcs) server and client options.

Its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Coverage_Service) may provide a good start, but also take a look at any Q&As here that are tagged [wcs](/questions/tagged/wcs).

The optional [GDAL WCS driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wcs.html) which allows use of a coverage in a WCS server as a raster dataset may be a good open source option for you.

Also, as commented by @nmtoken:

> You should also be aware of Web Coverage Processing Services (WCPS),
>   that allow a user to do complex analysis on the server.